# Why my Texstudio stopped searching "\section", \begin and "small brackets (" ? please help

Tags: texstudio

Small bracket is not taken into search as well as it is not searching `\section`, `\label`

[image]

It is happening with the latest version of texstudio 4.0.2

Comment: Although this is unrelated topic, but try to unselect the text and do your search again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens, because you have [image] — regex search enabled. Thus, parenthesis are special symbols, so either turn off regex search, or use this query

```
Kahneman/Tversky \(1979\)
```